# How do I send individual links to collect data in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to gather information and pictures from 100 college alumni.  How can I do this in a way where I can send individual links to each alumni member?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process to accomplish this in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

1. Create the alumni information form with all of the fields you want to collect, including a file upload field for the pictures.
2. Under Form Settings, enable Entry Sharing to allow you to send secure edit links to form entries.
3. Customize the entry sharing email template to ask the alumni to fill out the form via the provided link.
4. Under Submission Settings, enable Save & Resume so you can create incomplete/partial entries containing the basic information for each alumni without filling in all of the required fields.
5. Under Entries for the alumni for, create entries with basic information (like name and email address) for each alumni.  Click Save (not Submit) to save the entry as incomplete without validating all of the required fields.
6. For each entry, click Share, select Send an Edit Link, select Link Expires - When Submitted, then click Send.

This will send a personalized email to each alumni, with a partially prefilled personalized form that they will then be able to submit with the required information.

Here is what the entry link sharing experience looks like when managing entries:

[image]

Comment: Jamie - Thank you.  Does this mean, I have to take the $10/month service, until I want to hold this support for the site?

Comment: Yes, entry sharing does require a Pro plan subscription.